# ReadOnly Property in Custom Column Types in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, field, customcolumn

I'm creating a custom column in a feature for Sharepoint.  It is essentially this:

```
<Field 
  Type="Integer" 
  ID="<insert guid here>" 
  ReadOnly="true"
  Name="xxx"
  DisplayName="XXX"
  Group="YYY" />
```

When the field is deployed and attached to a content type, the content type shows no instance of this field being attached.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437580.aspx) about ReadOnly is a bit vague but definitely states that the column will be available for viewing in a View.  However, when I create a view it is not available.

The moment I remove ReadOnly from the field, it is available on the content type without any problems.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried out the same schema in a dev box using SharePoint designer to create it. I have issues seeing the column until I change the type from "Integer" to "Number"

Not sure "Integer" is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting ReadOnly on the content type's FieldRef instead of the Field element?

Comment: Hi Dahlbyk.  I have and this also does not work.  Once I get back into the office, I'll be trying Nat's answer.